# Where can I find the full list of filter event subscription names for Outgoing WebHooks?

Tags: circuit-sdk

So far I have found these:

```
CONVERSATION.CREATE
CONVERSATION.UPDATE
CONVERSATION.ADD_ITEM
USER.SUBMIT_FORM_DATA
```

I'd like to know all available. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see them on the swagger page of the spec.
See https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/swagger/ui/index.html or at the sepc at https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/swagger

```
"enum": [
"CONVERSATION.CREATE",
"CONVERSATION.UPDATE",
"CONVERSATION.ADD_ITEM",
"CONVERSATION.UPDATE_ITEM",
"USER.INCOMING_CALL",
"USER.USER_UPDATED",
"USER.USER_SETTING_UPDATED",
"USER.SUBMIT_FORM_DATA"
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an official list, but this is what I've gathered so far:

```
CONVERSATION.CREATE
CONVERSATION.UPDATE
CONVERSATION.ADD_ITEM
CONVERSATION.UPDATE_ITEM
USER.USER_UPDATED
USER.USER_SETTING_UPDATED
USER.SUBMIT_FORM_DATA
```